# What options do I have to recover a compromised Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Here's the situation: My account was stolen, and name changed along with email.

- I have no chance of getting the original Transaction ID since the account was purchased in 2009.
- I do have access to all the emails that were ever linked to the account.

What can I do to recover my account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't help recover your account. Contact Mojang support.

Comment: We really can't help you much with this. If you were indeed hacked, you should have received email notifications from Mojang about changes with your account. Within those emails are links that you can use to help recover it in the event that you weren't the person that made the changes. Otherwise, you will need Mojang to assist you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the email that you used to pay the account with, then you can send an email to DIBS and get the transaction ID (supposedly only the owner of the account would know the ID) https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/361380-what-is-a-transaction-id-

After that, you can message Mojang Customer Support and see if you can do anything with it.

Hopefully, it'll help you and you'll get your account back ^^